# Is it possible to swap out urls pointing to MySite with urls to custom pages?

Tags: user-profile, custom-web-part-property, redirect

We've developed a custom userprofile page for a costumer. This page is supposed to be linked to by all default sharepoint buttons and links pointing to the MySite.

One example is the SharePoint SocialComment control which lists all nodes made to a page, also displaying which user posted that node. The username links to the MySite userprofile. What we want is to change that URL to point to the custom userprofile.

Is this possible or do we have to construct our own webpart, inheriting from the SocialComment control and then modify the display of users and comment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The /_layouts/userdisp.aspx page which is linked from "user hyperlinks" contains the following control:

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" id="DelctlProfileRedirection" ControlId="ProfileRedirection" Scope="Farm" />
```

I believe that when you have MySites enabled it will load a child control that redirects a user to that user's profile on the MySite host. I am guessing you can deploy your own DelegateControl Feature which injects your own redirection control, assuming you set the sequence to be of higher priority, so thaet it overrides the MySite redirect.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://solutionizing.net/2008/12/08/user-profile-mysite-redirect-via-delegate-control/) is an example of delegate control, that redirects request. This solution for sharepoint 2007, but it can be still applicable for 2010 version.

Comment: That's the solution we have used before and it still works for SP2010 (with a minor tweak as i recall)

Comment: What are the tweaks for this to work in 2010 though?